# Pass object key in ng-change

Tags: angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

Is there a way to pass an object key or value with ng-change in a multi select element where ng-options is an object?

In below example, the `$scope.check` function doesn't receive any paramter, but would like it to get either the key or value.

`<select ng-model="$scope.someArray" ng-change="$scope.check(key)" ng-options="key as val for (val, key) in $scope.options" multiple></select>`

where 
`$scope.options = {a: 1, b: 2}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your select, You should not use **`$scope`** in view, also use a variable for the `ng-model` and pass it inside the **`check()`** function

**HTML:**

```
 <div class="media-list" ng-controller="dishDetailController">
   <select ng-model="selected"  ng-change="check(selected)" ng-options="key as val for (val, key) in options"></select>
  </div>
```

**Controller**:

```
app.controller("dishDetailController", ["$scope",
  function($scope) {
   $scope.selected ;
   $scope.options = {a: 1, b: 2};
   $scope.check = function(val){
    alert(val); 
   }
  }
]);
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/D7FZ9kX4LEWGmYUXnJ7B?p=preview)**

Comment: Thanks for the response @Sajeetharan. I forgot to specify, its a multi-select so when an element is selected its added to an array. Need the ng-change to find which val has just been added.

Comment: @LiamCollins it behaves the same as explained above, mark as answer if it had helped https://plnkr.co/edit/D7FZ9kX4LEWGmYUXnJ7B?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Tried to get this working for you, here is the select

```
<select class="form-control" ng-change="vm.change(vm.res)" ng-model="vm.res" ng-options="value as key for (key , value) in vm.options"></select>
```

Here is a link to it working in [codepen](http://codepen.io/mattchewone/pen/GjXLEX)